# How to apply -Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes to all subprojects?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I have a project with multiple subprojects that use the **kotlin-multiplatform** plugin or the **kotlin-js** plugin and I want to use the experimental unsigned types in all of them.

So far I've tried this, which doesn't work:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().all {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes"
    }

    extensions.findByType<KotlinMultiplatformExtension>()?.sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings.useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes")
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add the kotlin compiler arg `-Xopt-in=kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes` to all subprojects in Gradle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to share configuration is via a [convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins).

I.e. create a file in buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/package/name/kotlin-mpp-conventions.kts with the contents:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings.useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlin.ExperimentalUnsignedTypes")
        }
    }
}
```

Then depend on this plugin from your Kotlin MPP subprojects by adding a reference to it in the plugins block: `id("package.name.kotlin-mpp-conventions")`.

Add more plugins for e.g. Kotlin JS projects. If there's some configuration you want to share between all types of projects you can create a common plugin that the other plugins depend on. You can also share data structures between plugins by simply putting them in a separate file and referencing them from the plugin files (like you would with normal code), I use this mechanism to share the list of Kotlin experimental annotations I want to allow in all plugins.

Be sure to set up buildSrc/build.gradle.kts for plugins:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I've reached this point with trial and error, so I'm not sure this is the right approach.

I had a multiproject build with some multiplatform, JVM, and JS subprojects, and I wanted to enable the `kotlin.RequiresOptIn` annotation. So I ended up setting this compiler argument for all kinds of kotlin compilation tasks:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    val compilerArgs = listOf("-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += compilerArgs
    }

    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.Kotlin2JsCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = compilerArgs
    }

    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompileCommon> {
        kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = compilerArgs
    }
}
```

I guess the same approach could work for `ExperimentalUnsignedTypes`.

Comment: This works for the Kotlin JS (and probably Java and common) projects but not the multiplatform projects. Thanks for the first part of the solution though!

Comment: This is most likely because my own multiplatform subprojects only support JS and JVM targets at the moment. For native there might be other compile tasks. I would hope for a more general approach though, this is kind of hacky.

Comment: This simply doesn't work for multiplatform projects with `languageSettings.useExperimentalAnnotation` (my own projects only have common and js code atm)

Comment: There is a common supertype for all these tasks. Maybe this will do the thing: `tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinCompile<*>>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += compilerArgs
}`?

Comment: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinCompile did the job thank you